# WooCommerce Subscriptions - change next payment date on subscription payment complete

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am working on a minor change to the woocommerce subscriptions operation for a specific scenario.

I would like to update the value of the ACF field after each payment for a subscription, and then if the field value is X then change the subscription date to null or blank. The idea is to disable subscription renewals in this scenario without changing the end date of the subscription.

**My ACF fields:**

- towp_payment_count
- number_of_billing_periods

**Thats my code:**

```
function towp_track_subscription_payments($subscription_id) {
    // Sprawdzenie, czy ID subskrypcji jest poprawne
    if (!$subscription_id) {
        error_log('Nieprawidłowe ID subskrypcji - track_subscription_payment');
        return;
    }

    $subscription = wcs_get_subscription($subscription_id);
    if (!$subscription || is_wp_error($subscription)) {
        error_log('Nie udało się pobrać id subskrypcji: ' . $subscription_id);
        return;
    }
    
    // Pobierz aktualną wartość 'towp_payment_count' z ACF      
        $payment_count = intval(get_field('towp_payment_count', $subscription_id)); 
        $payment_count++;
        // Zaktualizuj pole 'towp_payment_count' w ACF
        update_field('towp_payment_count', $payment_count, $subscription_id);
    
    $billing_periods = get_post_meta($subscription_id, 'number_of_billing_periods', true);
    if (!empty($billing_periods) && is_numeric($billing_periods)) {      
        if ($payment_count >= intval($billing_periods)) {
            $subscription->update_dates(array('next_payment' => null));  
        }
    }
    $subscription->save();
}
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete', 'towp_track_subscription_payments', 10, 1);
```

Comment: May want to ask ACF about this... ...not entirely sure what their process is for updating their fields.